# How to put remote internship on CV

Tags: cv, covid-19

Due to the current pandemic I started working remotely on a research project several months ago under the supervision of a physics professor. Just a few days ago we finished and submitted a paper to a peer-reviewed journal. Since I plan to apply to graduate school I would like to mention in my CV that I carried out a research project with professor A from university B. However, since all the work was done remotely I am not sure how it would be convenient to put this on my CV.

1. Should I put it under the "professional experience" section? If the answer is yes, how should I include it?
2. Or should I wait until the paper is published and add it under a new section called "Publications"? I guess doing it this way would imply that I did research and it would not be necessary to add it to "professional experience".

Comment: What makes you think you should list it differently than an in-person research project?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I thought I had to point out that I worked remotely, but given that most people are now working remotely I think there's no need to mention that.

Comment: Most undergrad projects (i.e. analyzing data) aren't that different remotely.

Comment: The fact that the internship was remote is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would list your internship as part of your experience and, if you think it's relevant (I'm not sure it is), mention that it was remote.  List your paper as submitted for publication.  If it's ultimately rejected, you should probably remove it.  But for now, let's be optimistic.